# Unable to link IIS8 and Tomcat7 by ISAPI on Windows Server 2012

Tags: iis, tomcat, windows-server-2012, isapi, iis-8

Firstly, I am completely new to IIS and Windows Server. Previously I used to work only on Apache and Linux.

I want to link IIS8 and Tomcat 7.0.34 under a subdomain, such that when someone visits `subdom.mydomain.com` then only, IIS forwards requests to tomcat

I consulted these two references:

```
http://lab.usgin.org/applications/doc/make-tomcat-6x-work-iis7
http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/iis.html
```

and did exactly how they have shown. Below are the steps I have done:

1. Downloaded windows x64 ISAPI binary from http://apache.techartifact.com/mirror//tomcat/tomcat-connectors/jk/binaries/windows/ and placed that `isapi_redirect.dll` in a directory name `isapi` created under my tomcat installation directory.
2. I created a workers.properties file and placed it in tomcat's `conf` directory

```
worker.list= tomcatworker1
worker.tomcatworker1.host=localhost
worker.tomcatworker1.port=8009
worker.tomcatworker1.type=ajp13
```

3. Then I created a `uriworkermap.properties` file and placed it in tomcat's `conf` directory with following content(as I want tomcat's root app to run at the root path of subdomain):

```
/*=tomcatworker1
```

Then I created a `isapi_redirect.properties` file and placed it in `isapi` directory under my tomcat installation with following content:

```
# Configuration file for the Jakarta ISAPI Redirector

# The path to the ISAPI Redirector Extension, relative to the website
# This must be in a virtual directory with execute privileges
extension_uri=\tomcat\isapi_redirect.dll

# Full path to the log file for the ISAPI Redirector
log_file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0_Tomcat7_ins1\logs\isapi_redirect.log

# Log level (debug, info, warn, error or trace)
log_level=info

# Full path to the workers.properties file
worker_file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0_Tomcat7_ins1\conf\workers.properties

# Full path to the uriworkermap.properties file
worker_mount_file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0_Tomcat7_ins1\conf\uriworkermap.properties
```

In IIS Manager, in main server node and selected ISAPI and CGI Restrictions feature. Opened it and add a new restriction with the following information:

```
ISAPI or CGI path = {My Tomcat Directory Path}\isapi\isapi_redirect.dll
Description = Tomcat
Select "Allow extension path to execute"
```

Created a new site with binding `subdom.mydomain.com` and in it added a new virtual directory with the following properties:

```
Alias = tomcat
Physical path = {my Tomcat root directory}\isapi
```

Next, ISAPI Filters feature under my new web site's node. Create a new filter with this information:

```
Filter name = tomcat
Executable = {my Tomcat root directory}\isapi\isapi_redirect.dll
```

At last, made sure that the ISAPI handler is enabled.

After doing all these things, when I accessed my subdomain, I came up with a run time error, which I don't know how to resolve. check out error at this link http://backops.cmee.in/

Comment: I have not had much luck with ISAPI connector for IIS 8. I removed it and used the [BonCode](http://tomcatiis.riaforge.org) connector instead. It was simple.

Comment: I get it working now. It was not that much tough, I you like I could share the process.

Comment: Even though you got it working my suggestion would be to install the Application and Request Routing module on IIS together with a common http connector instead of AJP in Tomcat. That is, since IIS is fronting go the IIS native way (which is also supported by Tomcat) rather than use the Tomcat way intended for an Apache frontend (which is not supported by Microsoft). Or switch to Apache and use AJP instead of IIS with ARR and http.

Answer (score 1):

I never had much success configuring it unless the virtual directory used the name **jakarta** and nothing else. The *conf* and *logs* directories needed to be subdirectories of the ISAPI installation directory.

If you created those .properties files using a right-click and New Text Document, that Windows didn't add a .txt extension to them.

Finally, use **127.0.0.1** instead of **localhost** in your workers.properties. I don't know why but it doesn't work using localhost on Windows 2012.

Comment: I get it working now. It was not that much tough, I you like I could share the process.

Comment: Sure. I'd like to know what you did to get it working.

Comment: The answer is old, but maybe you (or someone) still is puzzled on why `localhost` sometimes is working and sometimes it isn't: These days it's often aliased to `::1`, which is the IPV6 version of localhost. If a server only answers on IPV4, naturally you can't reach it. Happy 20th birthday to IPV6.